# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmessage' of undefined, Ionic React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, service-worker, web-worker

I'm working on a metronome app in Ionic React and am trying to follow this GitHub example: https://github.com/francoischalifour/react-metronome. However, when I try to run the metronome currently nothing is happening, although it seems to be going into the start() function in metronome.js and returning this error in the console in Google Chrome:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmessage' of undefined.

I am new to using the Web Workers API, so I think something may be going wrong there. This is how I am calling the metronome from a file called Home.tsx:

```
<Metronome tempo={69} beatsPerMeasure = {4}
              render={({
                tempo,
                beatsPerMeasure,
                playing,
                beat,
                onPlay,
                onTempoChange,
              }) => (
              <IonButton onClick = {onPlay}>Start Metronome</IonButton>
```

Please let me know if you can provide any help or if you would like to see any other sections of the code. I have copied metronome.js and metronome.worker.js directly from the GitHub. Thank you!

Comment: `metronome.js` from your above github link needs `constans` file for the actions. Did you copied the constants file as well?

Comment: Yes, I have that file in my components folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay finaly got it to work, check here please, and let me know

[Running code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-metronome-demo-7lve9)

Also you may check other option for metronome, up and running here
I agree there an issue with code, you may check these two quick demos
[Demo 1 (Credit 2 toLuka Baramishvili)](https://codesandbox.io/s/metronome-demo-e9m3e), [Demo 2 (Credit 2
Alan Lavender)](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-tree-i8d69)

Comment: Wow thanks so much, it looks good but I don't hear anything when I click Play? Thanks for those other suggestions too.

Comment: Check your sound system, which browser are you running?

Comment: I was using Safari but just tried in Chrome and it works! Thank you again.

Comment: Great it is working for you, then you may accept the answer